# How can I perform Hapi.js/Strongloop validation in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, strongloop, hapi.js, joi

I plan to create an app with Hapi.js/strongloop backend, and with angularjs frontend.

Since both BE frameworks have some kind of model validation (Joi for Hapi, and Strongloop's own validation), I thought that it would be great to use these validation schemas on the frontend.

Is this possible at all? If yes, how can I migrate the joi/strongloop validation libraries to the client?

- What is fixed: we will use AngularJS for the frontend.
- What we have: data validation shemas defined in Joi.
- What I would like to do: use the same schemas from AngularJS (without calling actual methods on the server)

Currently we need to call a REST method (for example the Create method) to validate the form data with joi (or write the same validation twice).
We would like to change this so that the frontend can validate the form data without contacting the server.

Is there a way to use the joi NodeJS library in AngularJS?
If it is not possible, then is there another solution?

Comment: [browserify](http://browserify.org/) would probably work for Joi.  Also, this is kind of a broad and semi-option based question...maybe not the best for this site?

Comment: The frontend framework (angular) is fixed. The backend framework can change...
How can I include joi to the angular FE?

Comment: ...if the front-end is fixed...then...what is your question?

Comment: the backend and validation is not - is it possible to use the backend validation definitions on the frontend (for validating the forms there with the same code as the backend?)

Comment: In your question you ask "how can I migrate the ... libraries to the client?" but then in comments you say "the front-end is fixed".  I don't think you understand how the term "front-end" is used.  If your question intends to ask how to "validate data passed from the client to the server" then sure, Joi is made to validate data on Hapi.js servers...but, you haven't shown us any code or event hinted at the server design.  I don't see any way to answer your question because it isn't really a question, yet.

Comment: I have edited the original question, I hope I have managed to clear things up. (Will post some code later, currently I can't access it)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Strongloop, so I'll restrict my comments to Joi.

Joi is not built for client side usage. It won't even run client side even if you put all your code there. Check out [lib/index.js](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/lib/index.js):

```
var Hoek = require('hoek');
var Any = require('./any');
...

var internals = {
    alternatives: require('./alternatives'),
    array: require('./array'),
    ...
};
```

All those `require` statements will have to be rewritten so that it works on the client.

Joi also has some external dependencies that you may or may not want to include. You can take a look at [package.json](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
 "hoek": "^2.2.x",
 "topo": "1.x.x",
 "isemail": "1.x.x",
 "moment": "2.x.x"
},
```

So, no, without effort Joi will not work client side.

Comment: Joi generates validation error messages that may be returned to the frontend, parsed and then shown to the user. I think that's what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file for sharing Joi.

ShareJoi.js (Example in Joi directory)

2. Write the code below in the ShareJoi.js

var Joi = require('./lib/index.js');
window.Joi = Joi;

3. Install browserify
4. Run 
   browserify  ShareJoi.js > bundle.js
5. That is it, it is ready to use it on client side.

Browserify.js and Joi.js

```
<script>

    var schema = Joi.object().keys({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
        password: Joi.string().regex(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}/),
        access_token: [Joi.string(), Joi.number()],
        birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013),
        email: Joi.string().email()
    }).with('username', 'birthyear').without('password', 'access_token');


Joi.validate({ username: 'abc', birthyear: 1794 }, schema, function (err, value) { console.log(err); console.log(value); });  // 
</script>
```